# Average of a column value in model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating a website using Asp.Net MVC 5.

Suppose I have an online store. Each item has a review. I want to show the average rating for each item to the users. Something like:

```
                var average = items.Reviews.Average(i => i.Rating);
```

However, it seems like a bad idea to compute this average every time the user searches for an item. So I decided to somehow cache this value. My initial thought is to create a property and update it every time I update the table.

```
    public virtual IList<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public double AverageRating { get; set; }
```

and in controller (for create):

```
item.AverageRating = (item.AverageRating * item.Reviews.Count + review.Rating) / (item.Reviews.Count + 1);
```

This seems good but I wonder if there's a better way to do this. Or maybe I am wrong to think that computing the average every time would decrease my website's performance.

Comment: I don't think that doing the first approach causes a terrible downward of performance...

Comment: @AminSaghi even if I ran it for every single request?

Comment: Sure! There are many lines which performed in each request... One plus them...! Indeed, it depends on the amount of your data...